# Can '.*' in regular expression matching, match with any substring?

Tags: pattern-matching, dynamic-programming

Given that:
 '.' can match any character, 
and '*' can represent any number of characters of the preceding character,

won't '. *' be able to match with any substring, since '. *' can become '........' and this can match any substring?
Is it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `.*` can match any string. However, when you search for matches, it will return the whole string. This is because regex searches from the beginning of the string, and will match the maximum characters possible (in this case, the whole string.) If you want it to match the minimum characters possible you can use the `?` symbol after the `*`. [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers)

Comment: Actually there was an editing mistake, I hope you got what I meant. (I've edited it, now)

Comment: And, actually, I'm referring to a leetcode question, where they haven't mentioned about '?' in the problem statement. But, thank you, anyway